# Applying the hook modifiers will ruin my animation

Tags: animation, .fbx, hook-modifier

I need to apply the hook modifiers in order to export my walking animation but if I do so the ropes will stop following the joints of the legs. What can I do?

[image]

Update:
I baked the animation and it now runs nicely without modifier or constraints; but, when I export it as an fbx file the legs would walk while the ropes stay levitating.

[image]

Comment: Some form of animation baking, probably… IDK. Try looking at “bake to keyframes,” maybe?

Comment: Is your walking animation on a rig? My first thought is to weight paint the ropes to the rig, you might need to join the meshes.

Comment: I parented the rope to the rig through empty groups and then assigned the vertex groups. The animation works completely fine in blender but when I export it as an fbx the file doesn't load, in order for it to load I have to export the mesh without the armature which makes it work fine except for the ropes.

Comment: what about providing your blend file so we can check it out?